# How to ensure if multipath discovery is complete?

Tags: ubuntu, rhel, multipath-storage

On my machine, the multipath discovery takes random amount of time to discover and map all the disks under /dev/mapper directory.

The number of disks to be discovered is not constant.

How to ensure the multipath discovery is complete ?